# Bluetooth LE Error 133 triggers disconnection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm calling `mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(data)` in my app which is connected to a Bluetooth LE device. Sometimes the corresponding `onCharacteristicRead()` method is called with status 133. Immediately after this error, the device will be disconnected by Android (state changes to disconnected).

Does anybody know, why the error 133 occurs *and* why the device gets disconnected by Android afterwards? How can the disconnection be prevented?

Thanks
Ben

Comment: Bluedroid error 0x85 is just GATT_ERROR, which can happen for many reasons e.g. the characteristic has disappeared, the peripheral sent a message bigger than MTU, etc. Can you check `adb logcat` for any “bt-...” messages? Can you enable hcidump logging in Developer Options and download it using `adb pull /sdcard/btsnoop_hci.log`?

Comment: Also, what version of Android and device are you using? A lot of people also have seen status 133; see [Issue 58381: Bluetooth LE pretty instable](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58381)

Answer (score 2):

I've had a status 133 when connecting to a bluetooth device where I've connected to before, but the firmware has changed in the since the last time I was connected to it. I've been able to fix this by clearing the bluetooth cache of the android device (by turning bluetooth on and off).